Troubles formatting a complex excel file into a pandas dataframe for data analysis
I am trying to process a file with pandas to find correlation between variables and a specific result I get, but it is formatted in a way that makes it hard for me. I've been stuck for days and I would appreciate any help.
Quick explanation of the problem :
I am producing a product, and I get the final result after 6 iterations of the same procedure.
I’ll call a BIG BATCH the ensemble of the 6 iterations, and i’ll call each iteration a « batch ».
I collect data during each iteration regarding multiple parameters.
When all 6 iterations are done, I combine them all to get the final product, then I test the product, and that test yields me a percentage between 0 % to a 100 %.
(My product is good if my percentage during the end test is between 45 % and 65 %.)
I’m trying to analyse my data to see the correlations between all the parameters and the end result, to understand which parameters I should tweak and if possible in which direction to get my result between 45 % and 65 %.
Quick overview of how my data is formatted :
(This is a simplified sample with fake data)
Image of the excel file with parts highlighted
The issue i’m facing :
I can’t even get past the step of formatting the data properly with pandas in order to do any kind of analysis on it. I'm not even sure how I should format it.
What i’ve tried :
I’ll post my best attempt so far without all the failed trials, but i’m not even sure i’m going anywhere. I was trying to create a column for each Big Batch to put the results in, and create a multi-index to regroup things per « Big step »/Parameters/Big batch/batch, but the last part gives me troubles, and the first part i’m not even sure how i’m going to exploit it properly afterwards.
Any advices is appreciated.
Code below :
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

url = "path\simplified fake data.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(url, sheet_name='Feuille2', header=None)
# Extract and transpose the first two rows
first_two_rows = df.iloc[:1]
transposed_headers = first_two_rows.T
# Drop the first two rows
df = df.iloc[1:]

df.loc[2,0] = "General"
df.loc[1,0] = "test"
new_row = ["General", "Final test", "45% - 65%"] + [np.nan] * (df.shape[1] - 3)
df.loc[3] = new_row

def add_column_every_n(df, n, new_col_name, new_col_value):
    num_cols = df.shape[1]
    cpt = 0
    for i in range(n+3, num_cols  +int(num_cols/n), n + 1):
        df.insert(i, new_col_name + str(i), new_col_value)
        df.iloc[2,i] = first_two_row.iloc[0,i-n-cpt]
        df.iloc[1,i] = "Lot"
        cpt = cpt + 1
    return df

df = add_column_every_n(df, 6, 'NewCol', pd.NA)

df.head()


result of df.head()
# Forward fill the remaining NaNs
df[0] = df[0].ffill()
df.iloc[0,:] = df.iloc[0,:].ffill()
df.head()

result of df.head()
df = df.T

new_headers = df.iloc[:2].values.tolist()

# Drop the first two rows from the dataframe
df = df.iloc[2:]

# Combine the first two rows to form multi-level headers
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(new_headers)
df.head()


result of df.head()
What I think I want in the end :
Honestly, i’m not even sure what I want in the end is the right way to go about it in order to get exploitable data for analysis. So if you have any better suggestions, i’m all ears.
Here is how I think it should look like :
My idea of how I think it should look like (maybe i'm wrong)
Any advice on how to handle such a dataset, even just how I should format it in the end to be able to use pandas/other libraries to analyse it would be appreciated.
I tried my best, followed tutorials on youtube, a course on coursera, but they never explain how to tackle such complex problems so I feel lost :(

Maybe it will be easier to make data more tidy in excel (making another sheet where data will be represented more machine-friendly way).
And by tidy a mean "Big butch number/iteration number/param1/param2/...../result" sets of columns (Or, you can make it rows as in your current dataset and just transpose it after reading).
https://dimewiki.worldbank.org/Tidying_Data you can read this definition, it is really much easier to work with data this way
